# WARN CSVHeaderChecker: CSV header does not conform to the schema. - but header is correct

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm trying to stream CSV files with Spark.
I'm inspiring of https://dzone.com/articles/spark-structured-streaming-using-java.

However I got the error :

```
22/03/07 13:51:52 WARN CSVHeaderChecker: CSV header does not conform to the schema.
 Header: 
 Schema: department
Expected: department but found: 
CSV file: file:///C:..../data/stream/employee/drop_data/02_employee.csv
```

Here my code :

```
StructType schema = new StructType().add("empId", DataTypes.StringType).add("empName", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("department", DataTypes.StringType);

//build the streaming data reader from the file source, specifying csv file format
        Dataset<Row> rawData = spark.readStream().option("header", true).format("csv").schema(schema)
                .csv("C:/.../test/data/stream/employee/drop_data");
```

Here my csv :

```
empId;empName;department
1;Name;IT
```

Comment: Looks like an odd path. Is that really what you've got?

Answer (score 2):

Do you try to change the delimiter value of csv file from ';' to ','?
Example from [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spark-examples/spark-scala-examples/3ea16e4c6c1614609c2bd7ebdffcee01c0fe6017/src/main/resources/zipcodes.csv) have column.

Comment: ok I do not have the warning anymore.

Answer (score 0):

HAHA I also met the same question,and finally I found I typed "XX.csv" to "XX.xlsx",So as Benoit said,is the problem of delimiter

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34184392)